# Shortening a javascript checking for CSS property support

Tags: javascript, css, browser

EDIT:

I had a script that checked for CSS property support, in this case hyphenation support. It was quite long, but with the help of the respondents it was shortened to this:

```
var styleEngine = document.documentElement.style;
if  ((!('hyphens' in styleEngine)) && (!('MozHyphens' in styleEngine)) && (!('WebkitHyphens' in styleEngine)) && (!('msHyphens' in styleEngine)))
    alert('CSS hyphenation is not supported.');
else
    alert('CSS hyphenation is supported.');
```

The reason for this edit, including the title, is to make this post more useful to people to people googling for a Javascript that checks for CSS property and/or value support. I later learned a few things about CSS support and its check which might be of interest. The first thing I learned is that Chrome at this moment (2014) says it supports `-webkit-hyphens`, but it does not support the most important value `auto`. That means that we have to check for property **value** support.

That can be done in two ways. The first is with the new CSS at-rule `@supports`. That is explained on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports. The other way, with Javascript, is explained on http://ryanmorr.com/detecting-css-style-support/. And in the case of hyphenation, here is a Javascript polyfill for when proper hyphenation is not supported: https://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/.

Answer (score 2):

Extract it to a function:

```
function hasStyle(prop) {
  return prop in document.documentElement.style;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
if (!hasStyle('MozHyphens' && !hasStyle('msHyphens')) { ... }
```

Not too much shorter, but shorter enough (and encapsulated).

To be more concise, you can create another function:

```
function hasHyphens() {
  return hasStyle('MozHypens') || hasStyle('msHyphens');
}
```

And then:

```
if (!hasHyphens()) { ... }
```

Comment: with the OP's original code, we just need to declare some var to store the long `document.documentElement.style` to make it much shorter (and maybe is as short as this answer).

Comment: Thanks, King King. I once tried to shorten `navigator.userAgent.indexOf` to a variable and that didn't work, but I see now that shortening `document.documentElement.style` to `styleEngine` does work. Which indeed gives the shortest script. Thanks to you , too, Juan, even though King's answer is the most useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
ValuesIntersect(valArray1, valArray2) {
  var len = valArray2.length,
      i = 0,
      found = false;

  while (i<len && !found) {
   found = valArray2[i] in valArray1;
   ++i;
  }

  return found;
}
```

Use it like this:

`if (!ValuesIntersect(['hyphens','MozHyphens', 'WebkitHyphens', 'msHyphens'], document.documentElement.style)) {...}`

I find this is best for readability. When you're at that `if` statement, this clearly shows what you're checking for. The external function need not necessarily be *small* since it's rarely ever going to be checked. And it's generic enough to work in multiple places.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. For now, its just about the hyphenation, but if I ever need to check for more properties, I will certainly use your script.

Comment: @FrankConijn sure, happy to help - I personally love the 'make code look better' questions :)

Comment: @Saradh: shouldn't it be the other way around: `if (!ValuesIntersect(document.documentElement.style,['hyphens','MozHyphens', 'WebkitHyphens', 'msHyphens'])) {...}`? Also, you might be interested in the update of my question. Found a really cool script with which we can check property **value** support.

Comment: @FrankConijn Doesn't really matter, does it? :) I write it in my mind as "If these things are in this bigger thing", so the 'known' values come first in my personal convention... and sure, will have a look in a bit!